# CQ5 DAM asset: Not able to create thumbnail at renditions tab

Tags: aem

When I upload an image to the DAM and generate renditions, I sometimes find that rendition's thumbnail is not able to be created.

I tried to take a look at `http://localhost:4502/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html` but I don't know which step generate the rendition's thumbnails. Is it possible to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Thumbnail creation" process step (part of the `http://localhost:4502/cf#/etc/workflow/models/dam/update_asset.html`) creates the thumbnail renditions of the uploaded Digital asset in DAM.

Its common to see that the original document does not have a thumbnail displayed in the DAM renditions console. As long as you are able to open up and view the original version of the document and the renditions in their respective consoles in DAM, I think you are good to go!

If you click on the original rendition, the file will open without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid long loading times, if the image is more than 300KB of size then the document icon is shown instead of a full image in case of original rendition. Try uploading a file of less than 300KB in size and you can see the thumbnail in case of original rendition as well.

The rendition is getting generated fine, it is just not displayed on the UI. AEM 6 will be touch UI enabled and in the new UI, you will be able to see the rendition for "original" image as well.